# How do I deal with ' Cross Origin Request Blocked ' while parsing JSON file from any URL which containing JSON form data?

Tags: angularjs, backbone.js, cross-browser, cors, jqxhr

I am trying to integrate my code which is written in Backbone js with REST service which is placed on some different server. But when I am hitting the web service from my local machine console window of browser displays CORS blocked.

Comment: change server CORS settings

Comment: Can I do some settings on client side because server side settings is not in my hand. What I mean to say..Is there any way to enable CORS request by writing some code in jquery or in backbone at client side.

Comment: no ways... you cant change server's security from client... do you really think that should be allowed?? so any new client side/website can go and play with any site (e.g. banking site)

Answer (score 1):

Try my add on to enable Cross domain in client side when development if you are using firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cross-domain-cors/?src=ss

Dont forget leave a good review if it useful for you.

Happy coding!

Comment: This solution makes your browser vulnerable to attacks, don't use it if you also use banking websites on the same browser